# Golang parsing JSON with embeded XML

Tags: json, go

I have a http response body that is in JSON however it contains one field and that is an XML document as a string. I do not want to parse the XML at all, I just want to extract it because I need to send it somewhere else as XML. When I attempt to use:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
defer resp.Body.Close()
var ccr []models.Ccda
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &ccr)
```

The Model is this:

```
Ccda struct {
    CCDA string `json:"ccda"`
}
```

I get an err of "invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value"

I have attempted it with string maps also and still same error.

The beginning of the json response is:

```
[{
    "ccda": "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<ClinicalDocument xmlns=\"urn:hl7-org:v3\"..."
}]
```

ccda is the only element in the json string.  Again, I have no desire to parse the XML.

Is there a problem with the way GO is handling the escaped quotes?  The value of the json element ccda is the XML string.

Looking at the raw data from the vendor's site(their tool) I get this:

[{
    "ccda": "\n\n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n }]

When I read the response.Body and convert to string I get this (it is incorrect, though I may be able to use it):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
  <realmCode code="US"/>
  <typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040"/>
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1"/>
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2"/>
  <id root="0cf1a768-2016-505e-2fd3c-001A64958C30"/>
  <code code="34133-9" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="Summarization of Episode Note"/>
<\ClinicalDocument>
```

When I do other calls for other information in GO, I do get back the proper JSON on all tests go/ruby/site tools. just not on this call on GO.

Comment: Have you tried validating your JSON string? You can use JSONLint - http://jsonlint.com/ . Maybe a quote is not properly escaped and the next character after the quote is `<`, which is invalid in JSON.

Comment: I just checked it and it said valid JSON.  I would have been surprised if it was bad since it comes from a commercial site that has been using it for a long time.

Comment: My general advice is to do this in two steps; 1) unmarshal json with the xml fields set to `[]byte` or `string` 2) unmashal the xml into objects

Comment: The original is returned as a array of JSON entries.  I went back to ruby code and it all works fine with this code:
    y = JSON.parse x
    puts "type of x: #{y.class}"
    pp y[0]

So I have to assume that the json is correct because of this and the fact this is commercial running code.

Comment: evanmcdonnal: I get the same error using a byte array and string. THe parser is not liking the < after the quote that starts the data of the ccda element.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example, because the snippet you provide here works: http://play.golang.org/p/cQOlQ40Xy_

Comment: how can I get the body of the http get uncompressed?  I will be glad to send it.

Comment: I got the data by taking the string of the Body byte array. I could not put it in a comment, so I updated the question.  Something is very different.  Same call works in other languages, the sites non GO test setup.  On this one only I get the raw  xml when it should be xml in json.  I can request XML from the site I it is properly formatted with indentions.

Comment: I just spoke with the vendor and it seems to be a problem with go.  They are producing the json with the one element named ccda and the value being an XML string. It was confirmed it works properly on the other languages they support.

I am doing some further digging to be able to duplicate it with a small set of data.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON package is reporting a syntax error in the JSON text. To find the byte offset of the error, type assert the error to [*json.SyntaxError](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#SyntaxError) and examine the Offset field:

```
if e, ok := err.(*json.SyntaxError); ok {
    fmt.Printf("%v: %s <<--ERROR %s\n", e, body[:e.Offset], body[e.Offset:])
}
```

Here's a wild guess about what's going on: The response body returned to the Go program is XML, not JSON.  The program is not getting the expected JSON response type because the program is not setting the request accept header, query parameter or file extension to request a JSON response.

Comment: The error is exactly where I suspected the first <.  
I get this:


invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: < <<--ERROR ?xml version="1.0"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

However this is valid JSON. IT validates with jsonlint, It also runs with Ruby and I assume others since the commercial site it is from is live and has been.

Comment: @DonaldFrench The text in your comment is XML, not JSON.  Are you validating the response body fetched by the Go program, or are you validating copy / paste from browser or some other source?

Comment: The text is json.  The first and only json data item ccda has a content of an XML string.I am not trying to parse the XML. In fact I do not want it parsed. I need to pass it along exactly as I received it.

Comment: If the text in your first comment to this answer is the output from the print statement in the answer, then the response body starts with `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.  That's XML.

Comment: Then why do I get the proper data when using Ruby? and Python and on all other calls to other data, just not this one in GO?

Comment: Please provide a link to a Ruby or Python program that works.  Also, show the Go code you use to make the request. It's difficult to figure out what's going on with so little information.

Comment: I can give you the programs however I can not give you access. The site is a secure healthcare site.  Can not risk.  The Ruby returns the json directly I do not need to parse it.  I suspect because the response type is JSON.